# Angular 2 within VS 2015 how to import a package

Tags: node.js, angular

- I have installed npm install --save camelCase

  Which I want to use in my project.

  Typescript version 2.0.3

  import * as camelcase from 'camelcase';

  When I try to import into app.module.ts or app.component.ts I get an error
  Cannot find module ‘camelcase’

  ```
  How do you import packages?
  ```

  systemjs.config.js

  ```
  (function (global) {
    System.config({
      paths: {
        // paths serve as alias
        'npm:': 'node_modules/'
      },
      // map tells the System loader where to look for things
      map: {
        // our app is within the app folder
        app: 'app',

        // angular bundles
        '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
        '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler': 
   'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-
   browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-
   browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
        '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
        '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

        // other libraries
        'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
        'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-
          api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
          'camelcase': 'npm:camelcase'
      },
      // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename 
      and/or no extension
      packages: {
        app: {
          defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        rxjs: {
          defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
      }
    });
  })(this);
  ```

  **Package.json**

Snippet****

"dependencies": {

```
"camelcase": "^4.1.0"
```

},

Comment: install `@types/camelcase`, then only import would work

Comment: Hi Harishr, get an error in browser.

Answer (score 0):

That worked can find module for import but when I view in browser error displayed

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
:64054/node_modules/@types/camelcase/

systemjs.config.js
'camelcase':                 'npm:@types/camelcase'